# Is there a function for checkbox hide/show row in appscript google spreadsheet?

Tags: spreadsheet

I currently have I55:I231 as my tickbox option to hide and show the row, and the range is from A55:H231, some formula is not working for me, Is this possible to run a code?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const col = e.range.columnStart;
  if (col !== 9) { return; }
  const row = e.range.rowStart;
  if (row < 55 || row > 231) { return; }
  console.log(e.value);
  if (e.value === 'TRUE') { e.source.getActiveSheet().hideRows(row); }
}
```

Comment: Hi Genius, It is working Thank you so much!!!  You're such a big help. 

However, Is there a way to unhide the row by not doing it manually?
Cause I noticed when clicking the check box it obvious hide but there's no way for me to unhide - I tend to unhide the row manually

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Instead of hiding it, you could group and collapse it. However, consecutive rows would be put into the same group that the group (the consecutive rows) would be expanded altogether.